# Relative coordinates in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

Using ImageMagick I want to draw a primitive relative to image width

This does not work for me

```
mogrify -stroke white -fill white -draw "rectangle 100,100 %[fx:w-100]" -format png *.jpg
```

I think I do something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versions of ImageMagick before 7.0 did not allow `%[fx:...]` expressions in the `-draw` command options. When you asked this it would not have been possible. The good news is you can now.